# For $K,L \in H^*$ , show $K+L \in H^*$

Tags: functional-analysis

I am trying to prove for $K,L \in H^*$ that $K+L \in H^*$

In the solution, we first take a sequence $(u)j)_j \subset H$ such that $u_j \to u $ in $H$.

Then $$\lim_{j \to \infty} (K+L)(u_n)$$ $$= \lim_{j \to \infty} (K u_n + L u_n)$$ $$=\lim _{j \to \infty} K u_n + \lim _{j \to \infty} Lu_n$$ $$= Ku + Lu$$ $$= (K+l)(u)$$

> My question is, why do we need to involve a sequence $(u_j)_j$?
>
> Can't the proof still work without using the sequence and limits?

Comment: H* consists of continuous linear functionals, so for the continuity you need the sequence.

Comment: @arthursinulis   $H^*$ is the adjoint operator right?

Comment: I suppose H is a Hilbert space and H* its dual. Thus K,L are functionals.

Comment: @arthursinulis how do you know $H^*$ consists of continuous linear functionals?

Comment: This is a common notation, and agrees with the argument you gave.

Comment: @arthursinulis  ok